# the pointer vs pointer-to-pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am a little confused, so I'll start by explaining my understanding and hopefully someone can correct me and explain where I am going wrong. In C arguments are passed by value, so if we want to change the pointer from within a function that it is being passed to, we must define the argument as a pointer-to-pointer, such that we can then modify the actual pointer rather than the value. If this is correct, could someone explain how does the sprintf() function, for example, manage to change the *str pointer?

Comment: A"double pointer" contains the address of a double.  A pointer to a pointer contains the address of a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The `sprintf` function doesn't change the `*str` pointer, it changes the data that the `*str` pointer points to.

Example:

```
char *str = malloc(20);
sprintf(str, "hello %s", "world");
// str has not changed, only the data it points to has
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks :)

Comment: If the *str pointer changed, then the *str pointer would be pointing to somewhere different. It still points to the same location, just the data at that location has changed. For example, the pointer is like an address to a house, the data is like the people in the house. sprintf would be like replacing the people in the house.